# How to compute the intersection of a subspace and a cone?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, linear-programming, polyhedra

Let $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and let

$$S= \{y\in \mathbb R^n: y^T= \lambda^TA,\ \lambda\in \mathbb R^m\}$$ be the row space spanned by the rows of $A$.  Let $$C= \{x\in \mathbb R^n:  Ax\leq 0\}$$ be a cone.

How can I compute the intersection $S\cap C$?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I mean  $S=\{ \lambda^T A: \lambda\in R^m\}$.

Comment: @user1551   $S$ and $D$ indeed lie in same space.

Comment: @Ashkan You're right.

Comment: A bit of clarification is needed here. What do you mean by "compute the intersection"? Enumerate its vertices, or edges, or faces? Determine if it is empty or non-empty? Find its analytic center?

Comment: Hi, I mean finding some $B\in \mathbb R^{r\times n}$ such that $S\cap C= \{x\in\mathbb R^n:    Bx\leq 0\}$.

Comment: You really should have mentioned that ( $S\cap C= \{x\in\mathbb R^n:    Bx\leq 0\}$ ) in question. otherwise no one get that from the word " computing " .

Comment: So in other words you're effectively looking to enumerate the faces. I'm not confident that's tractable. But why would you want to do that? Why not just perform your downstream computations with the description of the intersection that you already have?